# ANSI -> Unicode на wince без русской локали

Tags: c++, кодировка, windows-ce

На девайсе нет русской локали, но т.к. wince (в моем случае 6.0) все выводит в unicode, русский текст он показывает (скомпилированный). Однако, ввиду отсутствия этой самой локали, mbstowcs и MultiByteToWideChar работают некорректно (выдают на выходе кракозябры), по сети мне приходит ansi. Что посоветуете?

Может у кого есть код "ручной конвертации"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть программки, скажи на какой e-mail можно отправить .zip (450KB).

Извини, там много всего, а аккуратно вытаскивать оттуда функции перекодировки некогда.
Если интересно, сами подпрограммы в ./lib/cnvrus.c примеры их использования смотри ./bin/mtrt.c (ну и в других тоже есть). Проблема - отсутствие документации.

Можешь просто написать мне на vpaqwe@gmail.com

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Написал

Answer (score 2):

Вдруг кому пригодится - рабочий код конвертации Win1251 в UTF-16. 
Как тут вставить ответ с форматированием - не знаю.

```
 std::wstring WinToUnicode(std::string text) {
std::wstring OutString, b;
BYTE c;

    //b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(255,254)); OutString=b;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < text.length(); ++i) {
            b = _T("");
            c = (BYTE)text[i];
            if ((c >= 97) && (c <= 122))  { b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(c,0)); }

            else
            if ((c >= 65) && (c <= 90))   { b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(c,0)); }
            else
            if ((c >= 48) && (c <= 57))   { b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(c,0)); }
            else
            if ((c >= 224) && (c <= 255)) { b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(c-(224-48),4)); }
            else
            if ((c >= 192) && (c <= 223)) { b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(c-(192-16),4)); }
            else
            switch (c) { 
            case 33: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(33,0)); break; case 13: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(13,0)); break; case 9: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(9,0)); break; case 10: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(10,0)); break; case 32: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(32,0)); break; case 64: b+=wchar_t(MAKEWORD(64,0)); break; case 35: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(35,0)); break; case 36: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(36,0)); break; 
            case 37: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(37,0)); break; case 94: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(94,0)); break; case 38: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(38,0)); break; case 42: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(42,0)); break; case 40: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(40,0)); break; case 41: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(41,0)); break; case 45: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(45,0)); break; case 95: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(95,0)); break; case 43: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(43,0)); break; 
            case 61: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(61,0)); break; case 92: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(92,0)); break; case 47: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(47,0)); break; case 124: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(124,0)); break; case 46: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(46,0)); break; case 44: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(44,0)); break; case 59: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(59,0)); break; case 58: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(58,0)); break; case 123: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(123,0)); break; 
            case 125: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(125,0)); break; case 63: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(63,0)); break; case 60: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(60,0)); break; case 62: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(62,0)); break; case 34: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(34,0)); break; case 91: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(91,0)); break; case 93: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(93,0)); break; case 96: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(96,0)); break; case 126: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(126,0)); break; 
            case 185: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(22,33)); break; case 184: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(81,4)); break; case 168: b+=(wchar_t)(MAKEWORD(1,4)); break;
                default: break;
            }
            OutString+=b;
    }
    return OutString;
```

}

Comment: Молодец, отлично !